# Java Quicksort pivot selection

Tags: java, sorting, pivot, quicksort

So when selecting the pivot in different ways I've run into stack overflow errors when selecting anything but the last element in the incoming arraylist.  On the "median of 3" type of selection is where it's happening the most.

```
public static <T> void quickSort (ArrayList<T> incomingArray, Comparator<? super T> cmp, int start, int end)
{
    if(start >= end) 
        return;

    T pivot = incomingArray.get(start + ((end - start)/2)); <--Stack overflow

    if(cmp.compare(incomingArray.get(start + ((end - start)/2)), incomingArray.get(0)) < 0)
    {
        swap(incomingArray, (start + ((end - start)/2)), 0);
    }
    if(cmp.compare(incomingArray.get(end), incomingArray.get(start + ((end - start)/2))) < 0)
    {
        swap(incomingArray, end, (start + ((end - start)/2)));
    }
    if(cmp.compare(incomingArray.get((start + ((end - start)/2))), incomingArray.get(end)) < 0)
    {
        swap(incomingArray, 0, end);
    }

    swap(incomingArray, (start + ((end - start)/2)), end);

    pivot = incomingArray.get(end);

    int leftBound = 0;
    int rightBound = end - 1;

    while(leftBound < rightBound)
    {
        while(cmp.compare(incomingArray.get(leftBound), pivot) <= 0 && leftBound < rightBound)
            leftBound++;
        while(cmp.compare(incomingArray.get(rightBound), pivot) >= 0 && leftBound < rightBound)
            rightBound--;

        swap(incomingArray, leftBound, rightBound);
    }

    swap(incomingArray, rightBound, end);

    quickSort(incomingArray, cmp, start, leftBound);
    quickSort(incomingArray, cmp, rightBound + 1, end);



}
```

The swap call just changes out the values at the index locations in the passed array.

Comment: You got a question without question mark...

Answer (score 0):

First thing that doesn't seem to be OK:

```
if(cmp.compare(incomingArray.get((start + ((end - start)/2))), incomingArray.get(end)) < 0)
{
    swap(incomingArray, 0, end);
}
```

compares the middle and the last element but swaps the first and the last element as a result

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions folks!  Moving the median of 3 swaps around (they were in the totally wrong order) fixed the overflow error.  Didn't even see it so thank you Howard and hjhill!

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow might be due to an error in your implementation of quick sort. If I understand your code correctly I find some strange lines within.

Assuming that `quicksort(start, end)` sorts the subarray from index `start` to index `end` inclusively the following lines do not make much sense:

```
if (cmp.compare(incomingArray.get(start + ((end - start) / 2)), incomingArray.get(0)) < 0) {
    swap(incomingArray, (start + ((end - start) / 2)), 0);
}
```

Here the index 0 comes into play which most of the time lies outside of `start` to `end`. The same with lines

```
swap(incomingArray, 0, end);
```

and

```
int leftBound = 0;
```

Fix the issues with your algorithm and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy pasted your code and ran it for 100,000 numbers and I didn't hit any stack overflow problem. Are you sure your swap and compare functions are working correctly as expected?